# How to put new object into array of objects in state

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks, setstate

Basically I'm trying to display the weather of a few cities and I have to make a few api requests then take the data and put it in array of objects in state so I can map through it and render it. Problem is I don't know how to push a new object into state and make an array of objects. Probably doing this all wrong, still learning.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Container, Card, ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

const WeatherPanel = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = () => {
        axios
            .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${"Ohio"}&appid=${key}`)
            .then((res) => {
                setData({
                    description: res.data.weather[0].description,
                    icon: res.data.weather[0].icon,
                    temp: res.data.main.temp,
                    city: res.data.name,
                });

                console.log(data);
                return axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${"California"}&appid=${key}`);
            })
            .then((res) => {
                setData({
                    description: res.data.weather[0].description,
                    icon: res.data.weather[0].icon,
                    temp: res.data.main.temp,
                    city: res.data.name,
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Container fluid>
                <Card style={{ width: "50%", boxShadow: "0  0  10px 2px lightgrey" }}>
                    <Card.Header> Favorite Location</Card.Header>
                    <ListGroup variant="flush">
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.icon}@2x.png`} />
                            {data.city}
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Card>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default WeatherPanel;
```

This is what I want state to look like

[image: What i want it to look like]

Answer (score 1):

In the way you are doing it currently, you are setting the weather information of Ohio and then replacing it with the weather information of California.

Your goal is first add the weather information of Ohio into the array and then add to that array the weather information of California as the second element.

Here's how you would do it:

```
let ohioWeather = {description: "your stuff", icon: "...", temp: "...", city: "..."};
// the line below clones the previous "data" array and appends the ohioWeather element to the new resulting array
setData([...data, ohioWeather]);
```

Same goes for the California weather object.

Answer (score 0):

Do that like this :

```
setData( pre => [...pre,{ description: res.data.weather[0].description,icon: res.data.weather[0].icon,temp: res.data.main.temp,city: res.data.name}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the data after every fetch.
Try to create an array before you start with axios.get, push each response to that array and in the end finally execute:
setData(arr)