# How to fetch api in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am using  axios to fetch api and i am not able to fetch api in multiple table row only one row display the data and when i refesh the page another value came out but not able to access the api in next row

[image: Console log Image]

Code for Axios

```
function getPostData(Player, IP, Port, channelName) {
    //console.log("insideFunction Row1"+Player);
    var data = {
      PlayerName: Player,
      ChannelName: channelName,
      Port: Port,
      IpAddress: IP
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log([response.data]);
      Postdata([(response.data)]);
     // Postdata(prevArray => [...prevArray, response.data]);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is `Postdata()`? Please show that method.

Comment: const [setpostData, Postdata] = useState([]);

Comment: Where do you call that? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-star-csop8    full code,                        first i am calling the axios in the function and use them inside the useEffect  and setpostData doing mapping Postdata () storing the response data which i getting from api

Comment: It sounds like you are replacing the current item in state with another item each time you make a POST request. You probably need to get the previous state and add the new data to it instead.

Comment: plz give me some code/example to  solve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put new object into array of objects in state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151258/how-to-put-new-object-into-array-of-objects-in-state)